$\eta(A)$ is not countably subadditiv
Let $\Omega =(0,1)^2$. For $A\subset\Omega$, we define: $$\eta(A) := inf\Big\{\sum_{k=1}^N \mu_o(R_k)\mid\exists N\in\mathbb{N}, R_1,....,R_N\: such\: that\:A\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}R_k\Big\}$$ where $R\subset P(\Omega)$ is the ring of elementary geometric figures, and $\mu_o$ is the corresponding measure on R. Prove, using the set $\Omega\:\cap\mathbb{Q}^2$ that $\eta$ is not (countably) subadditive, and thus does not coincide with the outer measure $\mu^{*}$.
$\;\;\;$So I was trying to use, that $B:=\Omega\:\cap\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a countable set as an intersection. And then using one $a_k$ sequence with $A=\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\{a_k\}$ and with Subadditivity of the outer measure: $0\leq\mu^{*}(A)\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu^{*}({a_k}) = 0$. Furthermore $\mu^{*}(A)=0$. But i don't see how this is going to help with the subadditivity. I will be gratefull to see any ideas. Thank you in advance!

In the definition of $\eta$, add  "$\in R$" before "such that"...
